# using a proxy with phantomjs in selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

I'm trying to configure a proxy with PhantomJS 1.9.1 in a ruby (1.8.7) script for selenium webdriver (2.25).

I saw a few examples with Firefox, and I successfully did it with this browser. I used this code :

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :ssl => 'chronos.landebitel.local:3128'
    $browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

But I can't find any examples for phantomjs. I searched and tried  many solutions, but none works.

Can someone can give me an example to help me?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Watir::Browser.new( :phantomjs,
    args: '--proxy=localhost:8181'
)
```

Comment: The only solution that seems to work for me, thanks.

Comment: Update with new version of phantomjs with driver_opts replace for args

Comment: @ThienSuBS that gives me an `undefined method `key?'` error. Using `args` as in the answer doesn't give me an error, but simply doesn't work.

Comment: @confetti Have you try something like that: 

Watir::Browser.new( :phantomjs,
    drive_opts: { args: ['--proxy=localhost:8181']}
)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to passing in a proxy to phantomjs you can also pass a username and password if the proxy requires authentication. Simply pass desired options in as a string array.

It is worth noting phantomjs support proxy authentication in this way and chromedriver does not (as of July 2013 anyway); it requires you enter the authentication into an interactive UI.

```
switches = ['--proxy=69.106.88.7:60199', '--proxy-auth=username:password123']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :args => switches
```

Comment: Replace args with driver_opts

Answer (score 1):

After years of searchings (really)

```
args = ['--ssl-protocol=tlsv1', "--proxy=ip:port", '--proxy-auth=username:password']
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36")
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => capabilities, :args => args
@browser = ::Watir::Browser.new driver
```

Comment: Thank you. Literally nothing else on this page or anywhere else worked. I don't know why it has to be so overly complicated, but this actually works for me to disable images.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this warning `WARN Selenium  [DEPRECATION] :args is deprecated. Pass switches using driver_opts`, you are still in the old version. The `args: proxy_arguments` is deprecated in the new versions.

This is what you need

```
Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, driver_opts: { args: proxy_arguments }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. I  just back from holidays and my problems is now solve.

I launch PhantomJS with this options :

```
phantomjs --webdriver=777 --proxy=serveur_proxy:8080 --proxy-auth=user:password --proxy-type=http
```

in my terminal and this line :

```
$browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://localhost:777")
```

in my script and it's work

Comment: --webdriver specifies the port to listen on. If the port number is under 1024, you'll need to have escalated privileges to start phantomjs. So I recommend a port number higher than 1024.