# How to pass browser parameter to Watir

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir

I am using Ruby and am using the latest gem version of Watir. I plan to use headless browser such as PhantomJS. How can one pass paramater to the Phantom JS browser when it get executed.

My purpose is so that Phantom JS do not need to load images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described on the [PhantomJS command line page](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html), there is an option to control the loading of images:

> --load-images=[true|false] load all inlined images (default is true). Also accepted: [yes|no].

During the initialization of a Watir::Browser, these settings can be specified, as an array, in the `:args` key. For example:

```
args = %w{--load-images=false}
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs, :args => args)
```

A working example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

# Capture screenshot with --load-images=true
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)
browser.goto 'https://www.google.com'
browser.screenshot.save('phantomjs_with_images.png')

# Capture screenshot with --load-images=false
args = %w{--load-images=false}
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs, :args => args)
browser.goto 'https://www.google.com'
browser.screenshot.save('phantomjs_without_images.png')
```

Which gives the screenshot with images loaded:

[image: phantomjs_with_images.png]

And the screenshot without images loaded:

[image: phantomjs_without_images.png']

Notice that the Google image of the page is not loaded in the second screenshot (as expected since load-images was set to false).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. Images are still loaded, other command-line args don't take any effect either. It works when I run `phantomjs` directly as a test with the args but within watir/ruby it's just not making any difference. Been trying and googling since hours, can't find how this is done now...

Comment: @confetti, Selenium deprecated their support for phantomJS as phantomJS itself is no longer supported. To get this to work, I would expect you need to make sure you're running older versions of Selenium/Watir. Though I would recommend finding another browser - eg Chrome headless.

Comment: Yes, I do have older versions and my Phantom works fine. I haven't tried another browser, maybe it's time to. But never change a running system.  This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969985/9138821 answer actually worked perfectly! :)