# Watir doesn't see element with Phantomjs

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir

I'm trying to take a screenshot of form with this code:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
browser.goto 'https://www.binbank.ru/landing/credits/'

browser.ul(class: 'r-buttons').li(text: '6').click
sleep 2
browser.screenshot.save 'a.png'
```

And `a.png` doesn't capture form. With **Firefox** as browser form is seen on `a.png`. Why is that? How can I interact with this form with **PhantomJS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS seems to have problems with SSL on that page. You somehow need to pass `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` to the underlying webdriver.

Judging by [How to pass browser parameter to Watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151204/how-to-pass-browser-parameter-to-watir) this can be done like this:

```
args = %w{--ignore-ssl-errors=true}
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs, :args => args)
```

Comment: that's right. I met issues with SSL and PhantomJS before (page wasn't displayed at all) - but I didn't know it could be possible that only a specific part isn't rendered. can I know how did you guess this was the issue?

Comment: I've written a plain PhantomJS [script](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/a4985bf31ff0adf12ca1) and when I saw that many resources aren't being loaded because of SSL handshake error, I tried some [commandline options](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) to see if they help.